# Extend stay in Netherlands

Tags: netherlands, singaporean-citizens

I am Singaporean and my husband is from The Netherlands and this is my first time here. How can I extend my stay in The Netherlands?

Comment: @rogani yunos Can you provide more information? Eg do you have a visa and if so what type and when does it expire? How long have you spent in the NL up to now and how much longer do you want to stay?

Comment: If you want to stay beyond 90 days, that question is best asked on Expatriates stack exchange. Family of a Netherlands citizen in the Netherlands would come under NL regulations rather than EU regulations, and it wouldn't be a tourist visa, either.

Comment: I’ve been in Netherland for 50 day. My question is can I travel to London for few days and come back to Netherland? Will my visa automatically be extended.?

Comment: I'm not aware of *any* automatic extension. Please edit your question to include the duration and validity of the visa you have, and the number of entries (single or multiple).

Comment: Are you traveling with your husband?  Are you visiting or planning to live in the Netherlands?